# How to remove particular class name from an selected element in VueJs?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, vuejs2, vue-component

This is what my vuejs methods looks like. Here in the changeRoute function I can change class name by `e.target.className = 'clicked';` But when I try to remove that class name from other elements I cant do it by `pre.removeClass('clicked');` How can I accomplish this ?

```js
<script>   
export default {

  components: { 
      
  },
  data() { 
      return {

      }
  },
  methods: {
      changeRoute(e, route) {
           
        var pre = this.$el.querySelector('.clicked');
        if(pre) {
            // pre.removeClass('clicked'); 
        }

        this.$router.push({
            name: route
        }); 
        e.target.className = 'clicked';
          
      }
  },
  mounted() {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
 
      })
  }
}

</script>
```

Also how can push class name rather than replace all by `e.target.className = 'clicked';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [classList.add and classList.remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) for this.
But it seems like you want to style link depending on the current route which can be done with vue-router as it adds class on the links matching the current route.
[Vue-router active class](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#active-class)

Comment: thank you so much. Actually I wanted to know the way of doing this in function. :)

Comment: Glad I could help @SwadhIn

Answer (score 1):

Use actual Vue to accomplish this task.
I could explain here how but the Vue page does it quite well.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: I know this technique but I want to know how to do it in vue function .

Answer (score 1):

If the selected element is part of a li list and class should be added (and consequently removed from previous clicked li), here's a good solution by Herteby on the [VueJS Forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-add-active-class-to-element/28108)

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-add-active-class-to-element/28108/2